# DataGrid with editable ComboBox for possible values in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

Here are some simple classes which have a many-to-many relationship:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace NodesLabels
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<NodeLabel> Labels { get; set; }

        public Node() { Labels = new ObservableCollection<NodeLabel>(); }
    }

    public class NodeLabel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        public NodeLabel() { Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>(); }
    }

    public class GraphContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NodeLabel> NodeLabels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've added `Node` and `NodeLabel` as data sources:

[image]

If I drag in `Node`, I get a `DataGrid` where I can create new `Node` objects, specifying their title. If I drag in `Labels` I get another `DataGrid` where I can add `Label` objects which will be associated with the selected `Node`.

Here, the `Node` `DataGrid` is on top and the `Labels` `DataGrid` is on the bottom. I've added "Dune" as a `Node` and given it a `Label` of "Book".

[image]

Now, I'd like to be able to select the node "Abstract Algebra" and associate it with the same "Book" Label. However, if enter "Book" into the Labels DataGrid, a new instance of `Label` will be created, with the "Book" title; i.e. the original instance of "Book" will not be reused.

Ideally, I'd like to have a `Labels` `DataGrid` with an editable `ComboBox` which will allow me to select from existing `Label` instances, instead of always creating new ones.

What's a good way to set this up?

Comment: Also, is there a book that covers stuff like this? I've seen many Entity Framework tutorials, some of which cover WPF, but haven't seen this example yet.

Comment: How are you adding it on drop , is the Node given a NodeLabel ID of book ?